# Generate JSON Object from Looping the Array

Tags: node.js

I have a requirement where I need to generate the JSON object to convert to XML, One of the parameter (SsNumber ) is coming as the String of array 'string[]'. But I am not able to loop the elements to generate the object

```
let SsNumber = ["123","234","345"]
const getSomeRequest = (SsNumber) => {
  return {
    $: {
      'xmlns:xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
      'xsi:type': "someType",
      key: SsNumber,
      keyType: 'Nbr',
      version: "1.0",
      pageItems: "2",
      pageToken: '',
    },
  };
};

const mapCustomerInfoEnvelope = ({ SsNumber }) => {

  const envelope = {
    'SOAP-ENV:Envelope': {
      $: {
        'xmlns:SOAP-ENV': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',
      },
      'SOAP-ENV:Header': "",
      'SOAP-ENV:Body': {
        Multiple: {
          $: {
            xmlns: "123",
          },
          MultipleRequest: {
               //to Loop here to generate someRequest
            someRequest: getSomeRequest(SsNumber),
          },
        },
      },
    },
  };

  return envelope;
};
```

As SsNumber is an array I want to loop and call the getSomeRequest(SsNumber), So that it generates someRequest based on the SsNumber.

Answer (score 0):

**First way: Use Object**

You can try to make a unique key for every object child:

```js
let SsNumber = ["123","234","345"]
const getSomeRequest = (SsNumber) => {
  return {
    $: {
      'xmlns:xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
      'xsi:type': "someType",
      key: SsNumber,
      keyType: 'Nbr',
      version: "1.0",
      pageItems: "2",
      pageToken: '',
    },
  };
};

const mapCustomerInfoEnvelope = ({ SsNumber }) => {
  let length = 5;
  let multipleRequest = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    multipleRequest[`someRequest${i}`] = getSomeRequest(SsNumber);
  }
  const envelope = {
    'SOAP-ENV:Envelope': {
      $: {
        'xmlns:SOAP-ENV': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',
      },
      'SOAP-ENV:Header': "",
      'SOAP-ENV:Body': {
        Multiple: {
          $: {
            xmlns: "123",
          },
          MultipleRequest: multipleRequest
        },
      },
    },
  };

  return envelope;
};
```

**Second way: Use Array**

You can try to use array element without specify key:

```js
let SsNumber = ["123","234","345"]
const getSomeRequest = (SsNumber) => {
  return {
    $: {
      'xmlns:xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
      'xsi:type': "someType",
      key: SsNumber,
      keyType: 'Nbr',
      version: "1.0",
      pageItems: "2",
      pageToken: '',
    },
  };
};

const mapCustomerInfoEnvelope = ({ SsNumber }) => {
  let length = 5;
  let multipleRequest = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    multipleRequest.push(getSomeRequest(SsNumber));
  }
  const envelope = {
    'SOAP-ENV:Envelope': {
      $: {
        'xmlns:SOAP-ENV': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',
      },
      'SOAP-ENV:Header': "",
      'SOAP-ENV:Body': {
        Multiple: {
          $: {
            xmlns: "123",
          },
          MultipleRequest: multipleRequest
        },
      },
    },
  };

  return envelope;
};
```